# How to cope with GERD in an infant

Tags: infant, health, diet

As a result of my baby being diagnosed with infant's Gastroesophageal Reflux Disease, I am following doctor's orders regarding my own diet so my milk is as easy on baby's tummy as possible and we have raised one side of her mattress slightly. This worked for a few months.

However, since my baby is now pulling, rolling and moving herself around more her head doesn't always stay on the "up" end of the crib so we had to remove the board that was raising the one end. Since she is old enough (7 mo), we are also very slowly and very carefully adding solids (mashed) into her diet. Now the GERD is on the rebound and she is having a lot of spitting up episodes again.

The doctor doesn't seem to have a lot of options for us other than to watch both baby's and my diets carefully. Has any one else dealt with this problem and what did you do?

Comment: Interesting that you say "mashed of course". They don't need to be mashed. We never gave our daughter mashed solids. (Look up baby-lead weaning.)

Comment: It would be useful to give the age of the baby.

Comment: It is [gastroesophageal reflux disease (GERD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastroesophageal_reflux_disease). Nothing in medicine is called "gastrointestinal reflux disease".

Answer (score 1):

We had reflux with one of our babies! We confined him to the living room for play and we covered the rug with a king-size sheet, so we could easily wash it. He outgrew the reflux as he eventually spent more time vertically than horizontally, so you are almost at the end - maybe a few more months! That valve just has to mature, and the constant irritation of reflux seems to slow that process. As he sits and stands more, it should begin to improve.

One thing you could do is make sure he is not overfed - maybe feed more often but less food each time. Make sure you burp the baby after eating. I would continue with soft foods as they are quicker to digest.

Answer (score 1):

Another cause of GERD can be a lip-tie or tongue-tie.  Check with your physician or a dental surgeon.  The extra skin can cause poor swallowing and lead to more GERD.

Fact sheet on [The significance of the tongue and lip ties and why you should consider correcting them February 2013](https://www.kiddsteeth.com/assets/pdfs/articles/ttfactssheet.pdf)

Comment: @balancedmama see updates

Comment: Hmm. . . interesting.